# Does upvoting a downvoted post redeem the 2 reputation penalty?

Tags: support, reputation

As we all know downvoting an answer gives the OP -2 reputation. Now if I myself upvote the answer after an edit. Will the OP get back his 2 reputation along with the 10 bonus?  Or does he get only 10?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If that original downvote was yours, your upvote will cancel that downvote, resulting in a net +12 reputation for the author of the post (and a +1 for you, because casting a downvote on an answer costs 1 reputation, and that is returned upon cancelling as well).

Comment: Why +1 for me????

Comment: @Vedant I clarified this now, see my updated answer.

Comment: Down vote costs -1 ???  OMG I didn't know that thanks

Comment: @Vedant Only on answers. Downvoting questions is free (for the downvoter).

Answer (score 9):

Because it's not entirely clear whether *you* cast the original downvote or someone else did, I'll just give you both scenarios:

**If you cast the original downvote, then cast an upvote:**

Two things actually happen here. First, the original downvote is completely retracted, causing all reputation effects from that downvote to be reversed (the user gets 2 reputation back, and you get 1 reputation back if it was an answer you downvoted). *Then* a new upvote is created causing them to receive 10 reputation in case of answer, or 5 reputation in case it is a question.

You can't have both a downvote *and* an upvote on the same post from a single user.

**If someone else cast the original downvote:**

Then all you're doing in this situation is adding an upvote to the mix, giving the user 10 or 5 reputation. The other downvote still exists, and is still causing a 2 reputation penalty.

***Unless*** that downvote was created automatically as a result of a "very low quality" flag being marked helpful, in which case you casting an upvote for the post will cause the downvote to be automatically retracted in the future, causing the user to get the 2 reputation back.

Comment: If you're aiming for a comprehensive answer, you might want to bring in the effects of reputation caps and the midnight cap reset ;-) Don't understand the downvote on this answer though. Let's reverse it!

Comment: you can upvote and then later downvote if the answer was edited

Comment: @Vedant In that scenario, the opposite happens. The upvote gets retracted first, and then a downvote gets added.

Comment: Yes. I was referring to that situation. Thanks I got the answer :)